# Finding rows of a matrix meeting some conditions

Tags: r

I want to find the rows that contain given column values. The first which() returns the expected 3 row numbers but last statement returns only 1 instead of 1 2 4 as I expected.

This example illustrates.

```
> x <- matrix(c(1,0,NA,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,NA),nrow=4,ncol=3)
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    0
[2,]    0    1    1
[3,]   NA    0    1
[4,]    1    1   NA
> which(!is.na(x[,1]))
[1] 1 2 4
> which(!is.na(x[,1]) && x[,2]==1)
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `&` operator, not the `&&` operator.

From the help page on `&&`:

> & and && indicate logical AND and | and || indicate logical OR. The
>   shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as
>   arithmetic operators. The longer form evaluates left to right
>   examining only the first element of each vector. Evaluation proceeds
>   only until the result is determined. The longer form is appropriate
>   for programming control-flow and typically preferred in if clauses.

If you're experienced with other programming languages I sympathize that this is confusing given that `&` typically denotes bitwise AND and `&&` logical AND